# siunitx update breaks things

Tags: installing, siunitx

I upgraded to v2.1 of `siunitx` since the version in ubuntu's package manager (1.3?) is pretty old. Things seem to have broken. I might have got something wrong with the installation, or I might be missing a dependency or something. I can't read log files well enough to work out what the issue might be.

I installed it by copying the `.dtx` file to my local texmf tree under `texmf/tex/latex/siunitx/` and then running `tex siunitx.sty` from that directory.

When I try and use the package, I get this error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\siunitx_cs_if_macro:NT #1->\exp_last_unbraced:No 
                                                  \siunitx_cs_if_tl_aux:w {\...
l.6 \begin{document}

Runaway argument?
{\token_to_meaning:N \bar macro\q_stop }{\prg_return_true: }{\prg_return_false: \ETC.
! Paragraph ended before \siunitx_cs_if_tl_aux:w was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.7
```

Here is `\listfiles`

```
 *File List*
 article.cls    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
 siunitx.sty    2010/11/24 v2.1f A comprehensive (SI) units package
   expl3.sty    2009/08/12 v1458 L3 Experimental code bundle wrapper
 l3names.sty    2009/08/08 v1452 L3 Experimental Naming Scheme for TeX Primitives
l3basics.sty    2009/08/08 v1453 L3 Experimental basic definitions
 l3expan.sty    2009/08/16 v1464 L3 Experimental Argument Expansion module
    l3tl.sty    2009/09/03 v1505 L3 Experimental Token Lists
   l3num.sty    2009/08/08 v1451 L3 Experimental token numbers
l3intexpr.sty    2009/03/20 v1086 L3 Integer Expressions
 l3quark.sty    2009/05/31 v1365 L3 Experimental Quark Commands
   l3seq.sty    2009/06/17 v1415 L3 Experimental sequences and stacks
  l3toks.sty    2009/06/14 v1412 L3 Experimental Token Registers
   l3int.sty    2009/05/28 v1362 L3 Experimental Integer module
   l3prg.sty    2009/09/20 v1545 L3 Experimental control structures
 l3clist.sty    2009/08/05 v1441 L3 Experimental comma separated lists
 l3token.sty    2009/09/22 v1550 L3 Experimental token investigation and manipulation
    l3io.sty    2009/05/31 v1369 L3 Experimental i/o module
  l3prop.sty    2009/09/16 v1536 L3 Experimental Property Lists
   l3msg.sty    2009/09/01 v1502 L3 Experimental LaTeX Messages module
  l3skip.sty    2009/05/28 v1362 L3 Experimental skip registers
   l3box.sty    2009/06/01 v1375 L3 Experimental Box module
l3keyval.sty    2009/07/13 v1424 L3 Experimental keyval processing
  l3keys.sty    2009/09/17 v1542 L3 Experimental key-value support
l3precom.sty    2009/08/08 v1453 L3 Experimental precompilation module
  l3calc.sty    2009/05/28 v1362 L3 Experimental calc module
  l3xref.sty    2009/05/28 v1362 L3 Experimental cross referencing
  l3file.sty    2009/05/28 v1352 L3 Experimental file loading
 amstext.sty    2000/06/29 v2.01
  amsgen.sty    1999/11/30 v2.0
   array.sty    2008/09/09 v2.4c Tabular extension package (FMi)
l3keys2e.sty    2009/08/24 v1494 Parsing LaTeX3 keyvals as LaTeX2e package options
  xparse.sty    2009/08/31 v1497 Generic document command parser
translator.sty    2007/03/11 ver 1.00
  keyval.sty    1999/03/16 v1.13 key=value parser (DPC)
translator-language-mappings.tex
```

And a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\listfiles
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
Foo
\end{document}
```

Comment: Updating the l3-related packages might help. `\exp_last_unbraced:No` is defined in the current version of l3expan.sty.

Comment: @Hendrik. I guess your comment and my answer overlapped! I'll add some testing code to `siunitx` this evening, so there will be more guidance rather than cryptic errors.

Comment: @Joseph: I should look up if you're on the site before looking at anything `siunitx`-related `:-)`

Comment: @Hendrik. Usually with relatively easy questions I'd wait a bit, but I like to feel I'm allowed to treat `siunitx` as a special case :-)

Comment: @Joseph: Well, obviously `:-)`

Comment: Version 2.1g including checks on both `expl3` and `xpackage` versions has just gone to CTAN.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is due to the version of the support packages you have installed. `siunitx` requires up to date versions of [`expl3`](http://ctan.org/pkg/expl3) and [`xpackages`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xpackages). Please update these as well, and all should be fine. (Thinks: this is becoming something of an FAQ. I should add some version testing to `siunitx` and give an error message if any of the support is too old.)

Comment: Was `tex siunitx.sty` in the relevant part of my texmf tree the right way to install siunitx? I sort of guessed... Installing expl3 and xpackages looks difficult: where do I put all the files before I `tex` the `.ins` files?

Comment: I strongly encourage you to download the pre-extracted files from CTAN. Look for `siunitx.tds.zip`, `expl3.tds.zip` and `xpackages.tds.zip`. These can simply be unzipped inside `localtexmf`, and will put the appropriate files in the appropriate places.

Comment: Sorry for the obvious questions, I've been confused by this before: So I put the zip file in `~/texmf/` and then unzip it there, and everything goes where it should, right?

Comment: @Seamus yes that's exactly what you do! Those TDSs take a lot of the pain out of installing new packages yourself...

Comment: i've got an "answer" about the l3 versions issue in my working version of the uk tex faq.  however, with places like tex/sx, it's clear that almost no-one bothers with the faq.  should i just give up? -- it seems that the time i spend on it is mostly wasted.

Comment: @wasteofspace As I've said many times, the FAQ is really useful, and many of us check it out before anywhere else. ('I know this has been asked, and there is a proper answer ...')